# How to extend a logarithmic function from the rationals to the reals?

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms, real-numbers

**Question**.  Say I have a continuous function $H$ with the established property that $H(p^y) = y H(p)$ for all rational numbers $y$.  How can I extend it to all real numbers?

**My attempt**.  Being continuous we have (by definition) that $\lim H(p^x) = H(p^y)$ where $x \to y$.  Let $(X_n)$ be a convergent sequence of rational numbers whose limit is $y$, a fixed real number.  If $x$ is an element of $(X_n)$ then $H(p^x) = x H(p)$ by the already-established property for all rational numbers.  Then we can deduce

$$H(p^y) = \lim_{x \to y} H(p^x) = \lim x H(p) = (\lim x) H(p) = y H(p).$$

I'm not concerned with proving such construction is clear and possible given current standards of rigor.  But I wonder if this strategy is at all possible.  My main concern is with the possibly wild statement "Let $(X_n)$ be a convergent sequence of rational numbers whose limit is $y$, a fixed real number." Does this work?  If not, how is this problem solved more or less properly?  (Feel free to just point me to a reference when the extension is done.  That'd be great actually.  Thank you.)

Comment: If it's continuous then $\lim{q\to x} H(q) = H(x)$.  So simply defint $H(x) = \lim_{q\to x; q\in \mathbb Q} H(q)$.  That's all....

Comment: This is a standard construction. It's commonly used to define powers $a^x$ for fixed $a$ and irrational $x$ even before you think about logarthms.

Comment: Thank you both.  I didn't know this was the very definition of real numbers.

Comment: Actually can you state *precisely* what the question is?  The way you have it worded *is* a legitimate question but it's pretty hinky and is setting off red flags in my mind.

Comment: The real numbers is an extended field with the lub property.  We *often* construct it so that a real number is *equivalent* to a class of rational cauchy sequences or dedekind cuts of rations. But even is we wave our hands consider: Let $x=x$ (love that laurie anderson!) for every $n$ there is a rational $q_n$ so that $x-\frac 1n < q_n < x$ (as the rationals are dense). Then $\lim_{n\to\infty} q_n = x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if I have the actual question and assumptions laid out?

You have a continuous $H:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.

We have the rather strange condition that for any given $w = p^q$ where $q$ is a rational number that $H(w) = H(p^q) = q H(p)$.

You want to know if we can conclude that for any $\omega = p^x$ where $x$ is real that $H$ has the property that $H(\omega) = H(p^x) = xH(p)$?

ANd this all assumes that we have defined what $p^x$ where $x$ is irrational is?[1]

You are correct.  By the *very* definition of the reals if $x$ is real then then there are always sequences of rational, $q_i$ so that $q_i \to x$.  That *is* what the reals are.

So.....  As $H$ is continuous $\lim_{q\to x;q\in \mathbb Q} H(p^q) = H(p^x)$.

And as $H(p^q) = qH(p)$ for all rational $q$ then  $\lim_{q\to x;q\in \mathbb Q} H(p^q) =\lim_{q\to x;q\in \mathbb Q}qH(p) = [\lim_{q\to x;q\in \mathbb Q}q]H(p) = xH(p)$.

Our claim is proven exactly as you claimed.

.....

[1]  But *is* that the question and have you defined what $p^x$ if $x$ is irrational?

Is the question actually if $S = \{p^q| p,q \in \mathbb Q\}$ and $H:S\to \mathbb R$ with the property $H(p^q) = qH(p)$ can we extent the definition to $H'(x) = \lim_{q\to x} H(q)$ and if we define $p^x$ so $\lim_{q\to x} p^q$ then will $H'(p^x) = xH'(p)$?

Was that the actual question?

Comment: The "rather strange" condition is the exponent-property of logarithms, $\log(p^q) = q \log(p)$.  So $H$ is a logarithmic function.  Yes, I want to conclude that we can extend this property from the rationals to the reals [with respect to the exponent], that is, let's relax the exponent and let it be irrational too.  Yes, I assume we have the real numbers already built.  What's not completely built is the function $H$.  I'm missing the irrational exponents.  So, yes, $p^x$ is defined.

Comment: "Was that the actual question?"  Almost. Your $S$ set doesn't need to restrict bases to rational numbers.  We have the reals available as numbers, but for the definition of $H$ we have only rational exponents.  So you can relax your $S$ as $S = \{p^q : p \in \mathbb{R}, q \in \mathbb{Q}\}$.  So the question is --- can we extend $S$ to $S' = \{p^q : p,q \in \mathbb{R}\}$?  The answer we seem to be giving is --- as long as $H$ is continuous.  Are we getting there?  Thanks for making this a lot more clear than when I started.

Comment: Well how is $p^x; x \not \in \mathbb Q$ defined in the first place?  We can and often do define $p^x=\lim p^q$ (actually $p^x =\sup p^q$ as $\mathbb Q$ is not complete).  If you have $x^y$ defined for all reals and you have $H(x)$ defined for all reals, it's a rather strange thing to declare a property that $H(x^q)=qH(x)$ for a rational $q$. Why only rational $q$?  Why and how would declare or know such a property?

Comment: If you can, take a look at section 6.2 of Richard W. Hamming's Coding and Information Theory, second edition, Prentice-Hall, 1986, ISBN 0-13-139072-4, page 104.  He constructs a function $I(p)$ to measure the amount of information emitted by a source relative to an event with probability $p$.  To do it, he assumes three things about $I$: it's nonnegative, additive and continuous.  The first and second assumption are client's requests (it's what we want) and the third is necessary to define it over the reals.

Comment: The second is what tells us that logarithmic functions are what we're looking for, but to make that clear he shows that $I$ obeys the same rules as logarithmic functions do.  Since we are building a function we need to define its domain.  Since we want the domain to be probabilities, we want at least the interval [0,1], which is essentially all reals.  I think you're right that by assuming what we usually assume about the reals, there is no difficulty here.  Hamming "solves" this problem in a sentence as you probably would too.

Comment: I'm reading it, so I'm looking into the steps a bit more closely and you have helped me to see a bit more about real numbers.  I think the main trouble for me here is that I think of real numbers as rational and irrationals.  Rationals are perfectly fine because they're defined wrt to integers.  I usually think of irrationals, though, as non-rationals and that's a problem --- because that's only a negation; it leaves me with no objects to play with.  To think of irrationals as infinite sequences of rationals solves that problem, so I tried it here.

Comment: I think the more detailed construction of the $I$ function is interesting for a reader that thinks more along the lines I'm thinking.  Hamming's one line seems too mysterious.  I think you do look at the problem correctly by remembering that this is indeed a correct way to look at real numbers and I think that closes the problem, so let's mark your answer as the chosen one.  Thank you so much for your attention.

Comment: I was taught in high school that the reals were "the rationals with the holes filled in".  Which was fine.  And I was told that as $b^n=b$ multiplied by itself $n$ times and that because $(b^n)^m=b^{nm}$ that $b^{\frac 1n}=\sqrt[n]{b}$ (and it was *never* questioned that that number makes sense and exists) so $b^q;q\in \mathbb Q$ so that $q=\frac mn$ and $b^{\frac 1n}$ and ... well, there was no question $b^q$ made sense.  And as the reals are just the rationals with the holes filled in, I just *never* questioned that $b^x$ made sense... but ... does it?

Comment: Any way... Not sure how he determined that $H$ has to property $H(w^q)= qH(w)$ but *only* for rational $q$.  Although I guess that can possible of $q$ some logistic defintion so that some $x$ will be of the form $w^q$ for a rational $q$. But the I don't really see how $H(x)$ is defined for $x$ in general *without* considering $x$ in the form of $w^q$ for some $q$. But it is cetainly not impossible.  So guess the whole thing makes sense. I'm just having a hard time figuring out the mindset that the question would even arise.

Comment: Also... from the big picture.  Once we put the reals under the microscope we know (at the end of the day... we had to work to *get* to the end of the day) that for any positive real $x$ and for any rational $q$ other than $0$ there is *always* a real $w$ so that $x = w^q$. So if you have $H(x)= H(p^z)$ and $z$ *isn't* rational, then just chose something else.  Chose $x =\rho^q$ where $q$ *is* rational.  ... So... I am wondering about the framework for this whole thing.... That said... the math be taking limits is just fine and works.

Comment: Hamming determines that $H$ has the logarithmic property by using the second assumption.  In the paragraph where he observes that this assumption is also called "the Cauchy functional equation", he begins his steps.  His first steps show the logarithmic property for integers.  He then shows the same for rational numbers --- essentially pointing out that it's not just integers that satisfy the property.  So that's how he determined it for rationals. For irrationals, continuity of $H$ is required and he mentions that next.

Comment: I couldn't make out your meaning in your comment "[a]lthough I guess that can possible of $q$ some logistic defintion [...]".  In trying to answer "I don't really see how $H(x)$ is defined for $x$ in general without considering $x$ in the form [...]", I say that Hamming began by describing in words the sort of function we want --- something that can measure the amount of information.  Here's the relevant passages from pages [104](https://i.imgur.com/fhgbAGO.png) and [105](https://i.imgur.com/wQVSznZ.png).  How do we define a function?  We specify its domain, co-domain and the mapping.

Comment: The domain is $[0,1]$ because the function's argument is a probability.  The co-domain can be $[0,infinity)$.  How do we do the mapping?  That's what Hamming describes.  After his steps we realize that the log function (any log function) gives out the mapping, that is, the pairs between elements in the domain and co-domain.  We couldn't quite use a log function [without perhaps making a restriction on its domain] unless our function allowed for real exponents, as the log function does.  So this explains all the steps he took in defining $H$.

Comment: By the way, I didn't remember he used $I$ instead of $H$.  The reason I use $H$ is because such definition was first given by Claude Shannon in [A Mathematical Theory of Communication(http://people.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/others/shannon/entropy/entropy.pdf), section 6, page 10 and appendix 2, page 28.  It's unclear to me whether the two approaches are really the same.